# Why yielding itertools.islice produce an unusable nested object?

Tags: python, generator, slice

I'm trying to split a generator into multiple parts so I can do some parallele computing. There is the main generator is produced by `g()` and `gslice()` is supposed to produce a subest of it and yield it for the rest of the program to use :

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from string import digits
>>> def g():
...     for i in product(digits, repeat=2):
...         yield "".join(['aa']+list(i))

>>> def gslice():
...     yield itertools.islice(g(), 3,4)

>>> a=gslice()
>>> next(a)
<itertools.islice object at 0x7fc4dc34ad60>
>>> next(next(a))
'aa03'
>>> next(next(a))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
```

Unfortunately as you can see `itertools.islice`, instead of spliting `g()`, is yielding some kind of nested object `itertools.islice` of wich you can take the first element once with `next(next(a))` but if you try again it produces an error. `list()` applied to `gslice` doesn't list anything but return the same object.

The goal of this post is basically to ask why `gslice` doesn't simply yield a generator that is a subest of `g` and also to ask how to do that. Imaging if I change `repeat=2` in the `product` method to `repeat=10`, why certainly wouldn't want to handle this other than through a generator would we.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`islice()` is itself an iterator (like a generator is an iterator). If you wanted to yield the *results* of the slice, you can use `yield from`:

```
def gslice():
    yield from itertools.islice(g(), 3, 4)
```

`yield from` requires Python 3.3 or newer. You could also just *return* the slice:

```
def gslice():
    return itertools.islice(g(), 3, 4)
```